# Vapor, why is drop.config nil

Tags: vapor

swift code:

```
let drop = Droplet()
print(drop.config)
```

result:

```
▿ Config
  ▿ node : Node
    - object : 0 elements
```

why is drop.config nil

Comment: Check that you're working directory is correct by printing `drop.workDir` and verifying it's what you expect. From there, make sure your config files are located at `<workDir>/Config/*.json`

Comment: My config files are located at <workDir>/Config/secrets/mysql.json. Why is the drop.config executed correctly after I delete the folder secrets?

Answer (score 0):

saying it works once you delete the secrets folder leads me to believe your using xcode and added the files directly through xcode. If this is the case, you should get the folder structure back to its original condition. Once its working properly, add the new files/folders outside of xcode, I add mine using Atom but text editor of your choice will work fine, then save the texteditor file and they will show up in your xcode project and work as expected with drop.config.

1) navigate to project folder using command
2) if using atom, type "atom ."
3) add the new files/folders and hit control + S to save

should be good to go from there
To be safe, make all future adjustments to files in texteditor as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening only on 3.1 because swift changed a folder with the dependencies and the vapor can not find working directory.

https://github.com/vapor/vapor/blob/1.5.15/Sources/Vapor/Droplet/Droplet%2BWorkingDirectory.swift

You should upgrade to the Vapor 1.5